# Query rows 9,000,000 to 10,000,000

Tags: sql, postgresql

New to postgresql, I have a table with 10,000,000 rows, I've been querying data a million rows at a time

```
SELECT mmsi, report_timestamp, position_geom, ST_X(position_geom) AS Long,ST_Y(position_geom) AS Lat 
FROM reports4 
WHERE position_geom IS NOT NULL 
ORDER by report_timestamp ASC 
LIMIT 1000000 
OFFSET 8000000
```

When I try and query the last million rows nothing shows up

```
SELECT mmsi, report_timestamp, position_geom, ST_X(position_geom) AS Long,ST_Y(position_geom) AS Lat 
FROM reports4 
WHERE position_geom IS NOT NULL 
ORDER by report_timestamp ASC 
LIMIT 1000000 
OFFSET 9000000
```

Not sure If I'm doing the query right, or im overlooking something.

Comment: I think you just have less rows than you were expecting, do a `COUNT(*)` to make sure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table may have 10,000,000 rows, but how many of those rows have `WHERE position_geom IS NOT NULL`?

What do you get with:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM reports4
WHERE position_geom IS NOT NULL;
```